# asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: the server expects 1 argument for this query, 2 were passed

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sql-delete, asyncpg

I want to delete element from array in this code

```
    async def delete_title(self, telegram_id, array):
    sql = "UPDATE Users SET title_id_list=(SELECT array(SELECT unnest(title_id_list) EXCEPT SELECT unnest('{$2}'::VARCHAR[]))) WHERE telegram_id=$1"
    return await self.execute(sql, telegram_id, array, execute=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced the same issue: the source was `colon+character` sequence (in your case it's `('{$2}'::VARCHAR[])))`), `sqlalchemy` is escaping such string when initializing query and reading it as an input parameter - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text.

Possible solution: you should replace `:` with `\:`